# Finding the position of a subsequence in a sequence

Tags: python, pandas

If T1 is this:

```
T1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'val':['B','D','E','A','D','B','A','E','A','D','B']})
```

and P is this:

```
P = pd.DataFrame(data = {'val': ['E','A','D','B']})
```

how do I get the positions of P within T1 ?

In terms of min and max I would like to see this returned

```
min max
3   6
8   11
```

If these dataframes were represented as SQL tables I could use this SQL method translated to pandas:

```
DECLARE @Items INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @P);

SELECT MIN(t.KeyCol) AS MinKey,
MAX(t.KeyCol) AS MaxKey
FROM dbo.T1 AS t
INNER JOIN @P AS p ON p.Val = t.Val
GROUP BY t.KeyCol - p.KeyCol
HAVING COUNT(*) = @Items;
```

This SQL solution is from Pesomannen's reply to http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/identifying-subsequence-in-sequence-part-2

Comment: Can you clarify the min/max result? How do you get there?

Comment: For the example data for the first exact match of EADB within T1 position 3 is where E is found and position 6 is where B is found. For the next exact match position 8 is where E is found and position 11 is where B is found.

Comment: `T1.reset_index().groupby('val').index.agg({min,max})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've worked it out by following the same approach as the SQL solution - a type of relational division (ie match up on the values, group by the differences in the key columns and select the group that has the count equal to the size of the subsequence):

```
import pandas as pd

T1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'val':['B','D','E','A','D','B','A','E','A','D','B']})

# use the index to create a new column that's going to be the key (zero based)
T1 = T1.reset_index()

# do the same for the subsequence that we want to find within T1
P = pd.DataFrame(data = {'val': ['E','A','D','B']})
P = P.reset_index()

# join on the val column
J = T1.merge(P,on=['val'],how='inner')

# group by difference in key columns calculating the min, max and count of the T1 key
FullResult = J.groupby(J['index_x'] - J['index_y'])['index_x'].agg({min,max,'count'})

# Final result is where the count is the size of the subsequence - in this case 4
FullResult[FullResult['count'] == 4]
```

Really enjoying using pandas !

Comment: I think the result he wants `J.groupby('val')['index_x'].agg({min,max})`

Answer (score 0):

well, you can always do a workaround like this:

```
t1 = ''.join(T1.val)
p = ''.join(P.val)
start, res = 0, []
while True:
    try:
        res.append(t1.index(p, start))
        start = res[-1] + 1
    except:
        break
```

to get the starting indices and then figure out the ending indices by mathing and access the dataframe by using iloc. you should use 0-based indexing (not 1-based, like you do in the example)

Answer (score 0):

Granted, this doesn't utilize `P`, but may serve your purposes.

```
groups = T1.groupby(T1.val).groups
pd.DataFrame({'min': [min(x) for x in groups.values()],
              'max': [max(x) for x in groups.values()]}, index=groups.keys())
```

yields

```
   max  min
E    7    2
B   10    0
D    9    1
A    8    3

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```